# OpenOffice Draw macro to find replace text

Tags: openoffice.org, openoffice-basic

I'm looking to find replace text within multiple PDF documents using Draw. Thus far I've managed to open the PDF however

```
mydoc.createReplaceDescription
```

appears not to be a valid property / method on a Draw doc.  Although oddly this is used in many examples for writer and calc.

Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after some playing around with the recorder in the Writer I managed to record a macro that seems to be more general purpose than the createReplaceDiscription I was trying earlier.
It's got a lot of bumf that I guess could be cleaned up but it works...

```
REM  *****  BASIC  *****

Sub Main

End Sub


sub WriterFindReplace
rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
rem define variables
dim document   as object
dim dispatcher as object
rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
rem get access to the document
document   = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
dispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")

rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
dim args1(18) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
args1(0).Name = "SearchItem.StyleFamily"
args1(0).Value = 2
args1(1).Name = "SearchItem.CellType"
args1(1).Value = 0
args1(2).Name = "SearchItem.RowDirection"
args1(2).Value = true
args1(3).Name = "SearchItem.AllTables"
args1(3).Value = false
args1(4).Name = "SearchItem.Backward"
args1(4).Value = false
args1(5).Name = "SearchItem.Pattern"
args1(5).Value = false
args1(6).Name = "SearchItem.Content"
args1(6).Value = false
args1(7).Name = "SearchItem.AsianOptions"
args1(7).Value = false
args1(8).Name = "SearchItem.AlgorithmType"
args1(8).Value = 0
args1(9).Name = "SearchItem.SearchFlags"
args1(9).Value = 65536
args1(10).Name = "SearchItem.SearchString"
args1(10).Value = "<<THE WORD YOUR FINDING>>"
args1(11).Name = "SearchItem.ReplaceString"
args1(11).Value = "<< THE WORD YOUR USING TO REPLACE>>"
args1(12).Name = "SearchItem.Locale"
args1(12).Value = 255
args1(13).Name = "SearchItem.ChangedChars"
args1(13).Value = 2
args1(14).Name = "SearchItem.DeletedChars"
args1(14).Value = 2
args1(15).Name = "SearchItem.InsertedChars"
args1(15).Value = 2
args1(16).Name = "SearchItem.TransliterateFlags"
args1(16).Value = 1280
args1(17).Name = "SearchItem.Command"
args1(17).Value = 3
args1(18).Name = "Quiet"
args1(18).Value = true

dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:ExecuteSearch", "", 0, args1())


end sub
```